# How to start the service at background(when application is not running)?

Tags: c#, winforms, service

Hello i have an application working with window service and i want to start its **service** at background, i mean even when the application is not running the service should run at a specific time for example: start(9am) and then stop the service at (6pm). 
Do you have any idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: How would anything be running if the PC has been turned off?

Comment: sorry i mean service should run before the starting of the app.

Comment: @MohsenRezaii to narrow your question down a bit, are you trying to ask: how to set up daily cron job for ___ in ___ language?

Answer (score 1):

If the PC is turned off then there is no way you can start a service. You need to tun on the PC and Login fist. There are some Services that can start on boot up though, you can start an executable after boot up by adding it to `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\BootExecute`. Never thought I'd see such question on StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

A service can't run if the PC is switched off. I assume that you want the software to run even if the user is not logged in.

If you want to run software without logging in, you won't have a user interface. Windows Programs without user interface are called services, and they can be started manually, or automatically whenever the computer is switched on.

As you have a windows forms application, you'll have to separate it into two applications: one with the user interface parts, and one with the parts that you want to run as soon as the computer is switched on. The latter part has to be put in the windows service software.

Whenever an operator logs in, he starts the windows forms program that holds the user interface parts. This program communicates with the already windows service.

There are numerous examples, also here on stackoverflow that will help you how to create and start a windows service and how to communicate with a running service.

Answer (score 0):

That's a server not a service, NOTHING runs on a personal computer when it is turned off, even when servers shutdown, nothing runs on them too.